# Can we access a DOM element without loading it in an infinite scrollable webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, infinite-scroll

I know the classname of the elements which I want to access on an infinite scrollable HUGE webpage. And, my goal is to access (get link address of) all such elements which has this particular classname. I can automate the scrolling and then access the elements, but when the page gets large it becomes almost impossible to scroll further (I could only scroll 1% of the webpage!). Is there any way that I can access all these elements without loading them? Or can you think of any alternate solution to my problem?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why would you need to access not 'loaded' element? Could you describe with concrete example your issue and expected behaviour?

Comment: What hasn't been downloaded to the client can't be accessed at the client. If your means of downloading are inappropriate, choose another. E.g. JSON or similar.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me whether the element is loaded or not. The problem is I can't load it!

I am collecting these elements as long as the webpage is scrolling successfully, but then it gets stuck at a point and I can't scroll the webpage any further due to huge page size.

Comment: `due to huge page size` so cleanup the DOM using any kind of logic. You could maybe provide online link where this behaviour can be check

Comment: @Yoshi- Got it. My way of downloading is inappropriate but there is no other way. Just one more thing, Is it possible to extract the source code of an infinite scrollable webpage without loading it? Like the way crawler works?

Comment: @A. Wolff Yeah. Thanks. That might work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a lot of overhead, especially when dealing with a (very) large amount of DOM elements. Your best bet would be to use vanilla JavaScript.

To directly answer the question, it is possible to access a DOM element without it being loaded, but it must be created dynamically via (for example) `document.createElement('DIV')`

Comment: As jQuery use internally when possible  vanilla method `querySelectorAll`, this won't make a big difference

Comment: While that's true, querySelectorAll is still laggy. Benchmarks show getElementsByClassName is far more performant. http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18

Comment: Ya that's true especially on chrome IIRC but i'm quite sure this has nothing to do with OP's issue (this is more relevant when called thousand times). Looks like more his issue is regarding too many elements displayed in DOM. I guess OP should find a way to detach some elements (these not in viewport) and use some kind of placeholder. But quite too broad question to be answered imho

Comment: Yeah, I was/am still pretty confused as to what exactly his problem was..